# KeystoneJS httpsServer property undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I wanted to connect socket.io with KeystoneJS trough https server, but i can't get KeystoneJS's https server instance.
I am trying to get it like this.

```
keystone.start({
    onHttpsServerCreated:function(){
        console.log(keystone.httpsServer);
    }
});
```

But it will retun undefined and when i log keystone i don't see any server property in it. Here is my sll init:

```
'ssl':'only',
'ssl key':'./ca.key',
'ssl cert':'./ca.cert',
'ssl port':'44433',
```

With http server it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed property onHttpsServerCreated into onStart and everything works fine.
But still I think this is a bug and need to be fixed.